# CLI: get CPU real speed (e.g. Intel SpeedStepping)

Tags: macos, cpu

Can you query for the real CPU speed in OS X command line/terminal?

```
$ system_processor
```

– only provides the hardware spec info.

```
$ sysctl hw.cpufrequency
```

– only provides the hardware spec info.

```
$ sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu
```

– this gives some good info.  But, nothing about real-time speed.

I see there is [Intel's Power Gadget](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20) that provides an API in C++, so one could go that route.  But, I am looking for a lighter alternative that does not require a 3rd party full desktop app installed - just to read the CPU speed.

For example, on my ArchLinux boxes I can just run:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

...to see the CPU speed.